# HOw to pass interface making it an class object and use its methods in another project

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have below situation :

I have One project "Logger"
which has class concrete class named "Log"
And this "Log" is inherited from interface "Ilog" which is refereced from project "Common" which has all interfaces

So now the solution looks like

MainSolution
-Logger(CLASS LIBRARY)
  - Log.cs

- Common(CLASS LIBRARY)

  - ILog (interface)
  - ICache (interface)
- Cache(CLASS LIBRARY)

  - Cache.cs (this class is inherited by ICache from common project.

Now cache.cs also needs to use Logging and i don't want to use reference of logger project, and just use the Common project reference and achieve the logging.

Please give some  way out of it.

Comment: Although you might achieve what you need, but I still say the classes could have been designed better based on their consumers../

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IOC to resolve this problem. By using IOC, you only reference the `Common` class library in `Cache` library; but call methods on `Log` class.

All you need to do is to create a container; map your interfaces to your objects by using either a configuration file or by coding; and resolving your objects by means of IOC.

You may refer to [this link](http://unity.codeplex.com/) and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649614.aspx#intro_examplecode) for Unity IOC.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, but in which project should i use the Unity framework?

Comment: @rusty you shall register the interfaces to the classes at the entry point. Then just resolve all other objects using the ioc container. This may not make sense at first look; but if you just refer to the links it may give you a better understanding.

Comment: hi i tried what u said, but my concrete class is in different project(Cache) and Interface is in different project(Common). I will be adding the Common project dll in my application. How can i use concrete class in my application of cache.

Comment: you need to add both dll's into the application; but in Caching Project only reference the Common Project; not the Logging project. e.g. Application references all three dlls; Caching references Common and Logging references also the common dll. Caching only knows the interface of the logging dll. Create a unity container in the application and map logging interface to the logging class. Then resolve the caching dll using the container.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't want to use the project that has the code in, but I do want to use it" is rather ill-thought-out.

Just use it or reimplement ILog in the Cache class library.